# How do I make custom buttons in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, button

I'm trying to make a launcher for a game that fixes some of its bugs.
Right now I'm just working on the interface and I want to make custom buttons, not just those generic squares, but I can't figure out how.

Here's some example images.

[image: Regular button, not moused over.]

[image: Moused over / Highlighted button.]

I just threw those buttons together quickly, but that's what I want.
I want the button to highlight when I mouse over it, without it being inside of the default square buttons.

Comment: What technology are you using for your launcher? WPF, WinForms, something else?

Comment: WinForms, sorry I didn't mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a picture box, and then added in my button picture with a transparent background. Then added a click event, mouse enter, and mouse leave event.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a custom drawn button. [This demo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172532(v=vs.100).aspx) from MSDN shows you how to override `OnPaint` and swap the bitmaps by responding to `OnMouseDown` and `OnMouseUp`. To get the image to change on hover instead, just swap the bitmaps during `OnEnter` and `OnLeave`.

Here's a cut-down example from the linked page:

```cs
public class PictureButton : Control
{
    Image staticImage, hoverImage;
    bool pressed = false;

    // staticImage is the primary default button image 
    public Image staticImage
    {
        get {
            return this.staticImage;
        }
        set {
            this.staticImage = value;
        }
    }

    // hoverImage is what appears when the mouse enters
    public Image hoverImage
    {
        get {
            return this.hoverImage;
        }
        set {
            this.hoverImage = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.pressed = true;
        this.Invalidate();
        base.OnEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.pressed = false;
        this.Invalidate();
        base.OnLeave(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.pressed && this.hoverImage != null)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.hoverImage, 0, 0);
        else
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.staticImage, 0, 0);

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```